# Протвинь (или протвень) и противень

Tags: этимология

В быту поддон для запекания чего-то в духовке мы называем "протвинь". Но, насколько я знаю, правильно он именуется "противень". Хотелось бы знать: это вообще русское слово? И, если да, то родственно слову "противный"? А еще интересно, почему в разговорной речи вдруг выпала буква И? Вроде как, такое произношения речь не облегчает.
По-моему, вопрос до неприличия глупый, но все-таки было бы интересно узнать ответ.

Answer (score 0):

Противень. И только он. От немецкого Brattpfanne - сковородка (особой формы). 
В русский попало после переосмыления - через "против".

Что касается дальнейшего "выпадения", то это обычная ситуация. Язык стремится к простоте, а сочетание "тв" легко произносится без гласной внутри.